# Create JSON from a JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have data which is come from a php function (SanatciListele())

```
[
{"sanatci_id":"11",
"sanatci_adi_soyadi":"Altan,
"sanatci_tel":"054333",
"sanatci_email":"altlu@hotmail.com"},

{"sanatci_id":"15",
"sanatci_adi_soyadi":"Zeki",
"sanatci_tel":"0533384",
"sanatci_email":"altanu@gmail.com"}
];
```

I have to create a Json like **sanatci_id:** **sanatci_adi_soyadi**
So  expected output is

```
{
      11: 'Altan',
      15: 'Zeki',
      
    }
```

I used this code but it does not work:

```
<script>
 var dizi=<?php echo (json_encode(SanatciListele()));?>;
        var k;
        
        var dd = [];
        for(k=0; k < dizi.length; k++ ){
          var KEY = dizi[k].sanatci_id;
          var VALUE= dizi[k].sanatci_adi_soyadi;
          dd.viwers[KEY]= VALUE;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want to acieve but I can tell you that `<?php` has to be at the beginning of any PHP code and must not be inside of it.

Comment: This is a Javascript code. I just use php for a function call

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question. And what is `dd.viwers`? In your code `dd` is an array, and thus does not have a property named `viwers`

Comment: I put  expected output, Thanks.

Comment: This isn't valid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.reduce()`:

```js
var dizi = [
  {"sanatci_id":"11",
  "sanatci_adi_soyadi":"Altan",
  "sanatci_tel":"054333",
  "sanatci_email":"altlu@hotmail.com"},

  {"sanatci_id":"15",
  "sanatci_adi_soyadi":"Zeki",
  "sanatci_tel":"0533384",
  "sanatci_email":"altanu@gmail.com"}
];

var result = dizi.reduce((res, curr) => {
  res[curr.sanatci_id] = curr.sanatci_adi_soyadi;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```